# Is this magic about iterators only, or is this a more general underlying thing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I saw this talk (specific timing is intentional

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lil4YCCXRYc?t=24m51s

On the board there's this piece of code (a similar one actually):

```
var it = [8,9 0][Symbol.iterator]()
//This gives me an ArrayIterator{...}
```

I noticed that if I try to do it in 2 steps, in Chrome, it fails:

```
var nums = [9,8,7]
var it = nums[Symbol.iterator]
it = it()
// in the console, this throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object(…)'
```

Almost knowing some javascript, I noticed that if I do

```
var it = nums[Symbol.iterator]
it.apply(nums)
// I again get the ArrayIterator
```

What's this magic about?
What's so different between `var x = obj[method]()` and `var x = obj[method]; x = x()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about the context. When you call `it()` it executes in global namespace and `this` refers to `window`. However it should refer to an array `[9, 8, 7]`. By calling `it.apply(nums)` you change the context that's why it works.

Another way to bind the context is:

```
var nums = [9,8,7];
var it = nums[Symbol.iterator].bind(nums);
it();
```

Now whenever you call `it()` it always runs in the context of an `nums` array.

Comment: What's interesting is that I knew about this context switching, and it still got me! I work mostly in Python, and there, what's bound, stays bound. You have to explicitly de-bind it, whereas in JS you explicitly bind it... cool, cool.